# How to make an app with android browser and a fixed url to work upon

Tags: java, android, eclipse, starter-kits

i am trying to make an app which is micro size, and when we click on app icon installed on our device it simple opens the web browser of android(default by android) wit a fixed url and on full screen headers padding title bar of the browser should be hidden,, kindly help me out with this thing how can i make such.

Comment: also tell me that will be needing the java script and css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many cross platform developement tools which lets u run a web app built using HTML,Javascript,css as a native application.PhoneGap is one such tool .you can find more info here http://phonegap.com/

Comment: Go to the link download PhoneGap for android set up ur project according to the documentaion and then you are ready to go.There's  pretty good documentation on the PhoneGap site go through it first.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

String packageName = "com.android.browser"; 
                        String className = "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"; 
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(entries.get(arg2).getLink()));
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); 
                        intent.setClassName(packageName, className);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);

Comment: sir i m new to this but i am understanding lil bt of the concepts of android, kindly tell me where n ow to write the code into ma app in eclipse

Comment: Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(Your_url));

Comment: still not working,, one more thing sir, where i can code a java script in the program? and also tell em a way to hide the addressbar of the opened browser so that everytime when i open  my app it should be on full screen representing a url